# Should I switch from D300s to D700?

Tags: nikon, full-frame, nikon-d700

I have the opportunity to upgrade my DLSR from a D300s to a D700. It'll cost me around $200 to do so. Do you think that it worth it?

Is the full-frame sensor of the D700 really that much less noisy than the D300s?

Comment: save up and buy a new camera - the D700 is 6 years old now, and misses many features seen on new cameras.

Comment: Not that the D300s is entry-level, but the same kind of thoughts apply.

Comment: @DarkcatStudios - The D700 is still an extremely capable camera. Other than megapixels (12), it's 8 fps, 51 autofocus points, great high ISO capability, etc. This is still a very fine machine and can be had for quite a bit less than new cameras with what are really comparable specs.